# Watson ignores inactivity timeout while recognizing "audio/wav"

Tags: javascript, websocket, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I try to implement Speech recognititon using Watson Speech To Text service.
I wrote some code in javascript using "MediaStreamRecorder" library. I send data through Websocket and get this problem: if I use "content-type": "audio/wav", Watson recognizes only first blob and set inactivity_timeout to defaul value meanwhile I set it to 2 seconds.

I use this code for opening websocket:

```
initWebSocket(startRecordingCallback) {
    var that = this;
    that.websocket = new WebSocket(that.wsURI);
    that.websocket.onopen = function (evt) {
        console.log("WebSocket: connection OK ");
        var message = {
            "action": "start",
            "content-type": "audio/wav",
            "interim_results": true,
            "continuous": true,
            "inactivity_timeout": 2
        };
        that.websocket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    };
    that.websocket.onclose = function (evt) {
        if (event.wasClean) {
            console.log("WebSocket: connection closed clearly " + JSON.stringify(evt));

        } else {
            console.log("WebSocket: disconnect " + JSON.stringify(evt));
        }
    };
    that.websocket.onmessage = function (evt) {
      console.log(evt)
    };
    that.websocket.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.log("WebSocket: error " + JSON.stringify(evt));
    };
}
```

And this code for recording audio:

```
startRecording() {
    var that = this;
    this.initWebSocket(function () {
      var mediaConstraints = {
          audio: true
      };
      function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
          that.mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
          that.mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'audio/wav';
          that.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
              that.websocket.send(blob);
          };
          that.mediaRecorder.start(3000);
      }

      function onMediaError(e) {
          console.error('media error', e);
      }
      navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);
    });
}
```

I need do recognition in real-time using websocket with socket auto closing after 2 second of inactivity.
Please, advice me.

Comment: There are better services for continuous audio transcription.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, maybe, but I need Watson.

Comment: Do you think you could post a complete example? Also, there's an SDK that may make it easier: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk

Comment: Hello Anna, 

Currently Inactivity detection is less strict than what's actually returned as transcript, so it may happen that the inactivity timeout is not triggered if the transcript is empty for a longer period than inactivity_timeout. 
 
The inactivity_timeout is triggered based on the output of the speech activity detection, so if this module thinks there is some speech the timeout_wont be triggered.

Comment: hello i'm looking for the same thing, did you find a solution?

Comment: @AhmedCommando, Watson's team said that this is bug. Have no info if they fixed it. 
I used this tools https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-speech to make it works.

Comment: @AnnaMotoshkina ok thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Bolanos said, `inactivity_timeout` is not triggered if the transcript is empty for more than `inactivity_timeout` seconds. The service uses a different way to detect if there is speech rather than relying on the transcription.

> If the service detects speech it won't trigger the `inactivity_timeout` even if the transcript is empty.

Here is a snippet of code that does what you were trying to do with your question but using the [speech-javascript-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk).
Hopefully, it will help future StackOverflow users trying to recognize audio from the microphone.

```
document.querySelector('#button').onclick = function () {
  // you need to provide this endpoint to fetch a watson token
  fetch('/api/speech-to-text/token') 
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function (token) {
    var stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone({
      token: token,
      outputElement: '#output' // CSS selector or DOM Element
    });

    stream.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

    document.querySelector('#stop').onclick = function() {
      stream.stop();
    };
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

Demo: https://watson-speech.mybluemix.net/microphone-streaming.html

Credits to @Nathan Friedly who wrote the library.